# Hide that pesky Try Edge banner on every Microsoft website

Tags: website, microsoft-edge, advertisements

This is what greets me on every single page from Microsoft websites that I load:

[image]

And it's not just there – it slowly animates into the view, moving all content row by row a bit to the bottom. I have to wait until that animation completes before I can dare to click on anything on the web page.

I've tried looking at the source code but couldn't find anything obvious to feed my ad blocker. Is there some technique to permanently remove that banner from Microsoft websites?

BTW, I'm using Firefox and I'm not going to change that. Other browsers serve for web development testing purposes only.

Comment: uBlock doesn't have a filter for that?

Comment: @Xen2050 No, it does not. It’s not *really* advertising, after all.

Comment: It's not just for advertising only, try the element picker or zapper mode, click on the offending stuff, and try creating your own rule to eliminate

Comment: You can block it using its element ID ("epb"), but IIRC there was some quirk. It’s currently now showing for me, so I cannot test.

Comment: Not showing up for me either, on regular microsoft.com english sites, or https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/hub/4337664/microsoft-edge-help, with or without ublock enabled. I wonder if it could be something else causing the ad, windows or another program...